# Is the initial horizontal velocity of a kicked ball also it's maximum horizontal velocity?

Tags: acceleration, velocity, projectile

The horizontal velocity that the ball acquires from the impact of your foot, will this be the maximum velocity, or will there be some horizontal acceleration at first, which results in a maximum velocity after which drag will slow down the ball?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering ideal conditions when you kick the ball at some angle the initial velocity of is in both x and y direction but as there is no acceleration in x direction the x component of velocity remains constant

---

In practical situation if u kick the ball , it will encounter air drag that will slow it down and eventually change the x component of velocity of ball because right from the moment you kicked the ball ,friction starts acting. If you kick the ball very hard it acquires some initial acceleration which is sum of acceleration due to your foot and retardation due to friction till the time acceleration provided by your foot is more , the horizontal velocity of vall increases but eventually friction causes to slow down and stop so of you provide some acceleration to ball its velocity will increase but if you kick by imparting some velocity then then that horizontal velocity will be maximum